# Get rows data from base with php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, pdo

Here I have an `dataRange` loop, but for this case its not important, more important than `dateRange` is `$i`:

So I have:

```
  $dateString = '09.03.2014';
$startDate = new DateTime($dateString);

$period = new DateInterval('P1M');
$endDate = clone $startDate;
$endDate->add($period);

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($startDate, $interval ,$endDate);
$i=1;
foreach($daterange as $date){
        $temp = array();
        // the following line will be used to slice the Pie chart
        $temp['ID'] = $i;
        $temp['datum'] = $date->format("d/m") . PHP_EOL;

        $rs1 = $db->prepare('SELECT naziv FROM aktivnosti WHERE user_id=:idd');
              $rs1->bindParam(':idd', $i); 

              $rs1->execute();
              $naz = $rs1->fetchColumn();
                      if ($naz != false) {
              $temp['vrsta'] =  $naz;
                      } else {
                         $temp['vrsta'] =  '';
                      }


        $output['data'][] = $temp;
        $i++;
    }
    $jsonTable = json_encode($output);
```

As you can see I have for loop and with $temp['vrsta'] I want to get data from table aktivnosti .

I also have JS UI layer on frontend which make a html from data:

```
 $('#example').dataTable( {
        "ajax": "table1.php",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "ID" },
            { "data": "datum" },
            { "data": "naziv" },
            { "data": "vrsta" },

        ],
        "lengthMenu": [ 31 ],
        "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 3,
    "data": "download_link",
    "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
      if (data != '') {
      return '<button class="btn btn-success">'+data+'</button>';
      }else {
          return data;
      }
    }
  } , etc...
```

**Now my code fetch only first row data so problem is becouse I have many rows on table aktivnosti** with the same user_id so when I have many the same user_id on aktivnosti I also need to create ''+data+''; for every row from table aktivnosti but I have NO idea how to do that?

Some ideas? How I can do that?

Comment: You should really loop those ID's into a string, and then query the database once.  But I'll give you an answer based on the way you've done it....give me a minute

Comment: Based on what you said in my deleted answer, then wouldnt you need to name data, data.data.  Because you're naming your array in PHP as data.  Meaning you're giving it an extra layer that it doesn't need.  The data in the DataTable code is referring to the response array.

Comment: please tell what is the best way to do what i want and write an answer. Thanks

Comment: my aktivnosti database - last column is user_id: http://i.imgur.com/wIoCcbN.png

Comment: What exactly is $daterage, that will help

Comment: Well theres your problem.  You are just creating a daterange, and then incrementing $i.  So $i will be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.  Not neccessarily the ID"s in your table, with matching dates.  Based on the fact you want to create a pie chart of sorts, and get ID's you have to rethink how to go about it.

Comment: I dont uderstand please write an answer

Comment: There really is no answer, because you are doing it completely wrong.  I can try though...are you trying to select ID's based on date?

Comment: hm, no, my problem is becouse I dont get multiple results to show it on frontend... everyithing just work fine, just I need to create a as namy buttons as many records I have - in one table cell

Comment: No, sorry...youre not doing it right.  Granted....you are getting 1 row returned, because there is one row that mathces ID 1. Because your $i value contains one.  But thats just a coincedence.  Nowhere are you actually selecting by date, and grouping by user.  Which is really what you need to be doing

Comment: the $i is in range (1-30) so you can see in code that I have $i++ that increment id, so id can be 1 - 30 ... not just 1

Comment: you probaly dont see that i have $i++ ?

Comment: Yes, but nowhere are you actually querying against the date, so what is the purpose of date range and why do you even need it.  By your logic you could just do for($i=0;$i<30;$i++) and you would get the same results.   You need to actually be querying against the dates, to get correct data

Comment: the purpose for daterange is only to make a 31,30,28 loop depend of month, so its just count how many days have month

Comment: Yeah I understand that.  But then you're just incrementing $i based on the count of the days, and using that $i to get user_id????  That makes absolutely no sense.  Basically you will always query values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ...30 .  You need to send the DATE from daterange into the query and then GROUP BY user_id, to get all records from that date range for the user

Comment: yes yes, apsolutly that :) make sense for me , for my app ;)

Comment: Sorry Ive been building apps for 12 years, and that makes absolutely no sense at all.  Dont you want all records from day 1, all records from day 2 all records from day 3???  The way youre doing it, youre just gonna get day 1, user_id1, day 2, user_id 2, day 3 user_id 3.  Understand what Im saying?

Comment: ok, lets say that instead user_id there is ID_field

Comment: so I put user_id just as an example, can you show me hw to get this data when I have many ID_fields  with same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will go something like this...

```
      $startDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("2013-01-01")); //put first date here
      $endDate = date('Y-m-d',,strtotime("2013-12-31")); //put second date here

      $rs1 = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM aktivnosti WHERE DATE(start_date)>=DATE('.$startDate.') AND DATE(end_date)<=('.$endDate.') GROUP BY user_id');
      $rs1->execute();
      $naz = $rs1->fetchAll();

      $jsonTable = json_encode($naz);
```

Note your date columns I named start_date, and end_date.  I have no idea what your columns are called though.

Comment: no no, i will post new question with better explanation

Answer (score 1):

Consider using something like this:

```
"columnDefs": [{
  "targets": 3,
  "createdCell": function(td,data,row,rIndex,cIndex) {
   // actions for every cell generated on the column you specified.
  }
}]
```

More info:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell

Comment: yes but what about php code, php code fetch only first row on table aktivnsti ...

Comment: I would need to see a sample of the data you have on that table.

Comment: are there actually any more records for user_id = 1 ?

Comment: there is few records for user_id = 7

Comment: ok for user_id = 1 is one record but for user_id = 7 is several records ... so I need to take this several data from all that records where user_id = 7